# Several questions regarding Levenberg-Marquadt implementation in Scipy

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, levenberg-marquardt

I came across a few oddities while trying to optimize a function using Levenberg-Marquadt algorithm in Scipy. I was wondering if anyone had an explanation for them.

A. I have an objective function that accepts two parameters with 2 residuals. As far as I understand, LM for scipy `root` using `sum(residual^2)` and `least_squares` should be the same. However, `least_squares` returns an optimized value while `root` fails. Are the implementations for the two functions different?

B. When I optimize the function using `least_squares`, the second parameter does not change from its initial value. Why does this happen?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please edit the question and post the code of you have called the `root` and `least_squares` optimization?